# VSCODE - How to configure docker compose problem matcher

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I've the following workspace configuration

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "launch": {
        "configurations": [
            {
                "type": "chrome",
                "request": "launch",
                "name": "docker-compose:launch:chrome",
                "url": "http://localhost:8080",
                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "sourceMaps": true,
                "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                     "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
                },
                "preLaunchTask": "docker:compose:up",
                "postDebugTask": "docker:compose:down"
            },

        ],
    },
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "label": "npm:install",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "npm install",
                "linux": {
                    "command": "if [ -d ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules ]; then npm install fi"
                },
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd",
                    "args": ["/C","if not exist ${workspaceFolder}/node_modules  npm install"]
                },
                "options": {"cwd":"${workspaceFolder}"}
            },
            {
                "type": "docker-compose",
                "label": "docker:compose:up",
                "dependsOn": ["npm:install"],
                "isBackground": true,
                "dockerCompose": {
                  "up": {
                    "detached": true,
                    "build": true,
                    "customOptions": "",
                    "services": [
                      "site"
                    ]
                  },
                  "files": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.yaml"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "type": "docker-compose",
                "label": "docker:compose:down",
                "dockerCompose": {
                  "down": {
                    "removeVolumes":false
                  },
                  "files": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.yaml"
                  ]
                },      
              },
        ]
    },
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
}
```

The launch("docker-compose:launch:chrome") configuration is not launching the chrome and I think thats happening because it thinks the task is not finished.

As far I know this should be checked using the problemMatcher, for vuejs as an example i can have the following problemMatcher:

```json
        "problemMatcher": [{
            "base": "$tsc-watch",
            "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": "Starting development server",
                "endsPattern": "Compiled successfully"
            }
        }],
```

How can i achive the same results using docker-compose?

I mean, is there a way to only launch chrome browser when the npm run serve command is finished?

Comment: define an empty problemmatcher: `"problemMatcher": []` and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: it launches the chrome, but the server is not ready yet. Is there anyway to wait the npm run serve?